# Category with children organization: wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories

Good day kind crew. I haBe a issue. what I am trying to do is this: a tennis league with 5 divisions. These 5 divisions are located in everytown and those towns in states. I am using ACF and pods. On the state archive page. We would like to choose the state and then on the specific state page we would see the divisions terms. And when you click the division you see all post from that tterm. We have a custom template for the taxonomy but want to limit how many template pages we need to create. If we go with categories than we have to make a custom template for every town/division. Any suggestions on best logic for this making it easy to use on front end without losing admin organization. We set up category hiearcy but we're looking for a better way because we need to allow for user to fill out form and populate post. At this point we have decided to use categories unless someone has another option. Categories just feel sloppy on admin side with children. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, and thus am not sure I'm on the right track with this answer.

I think you're looking for towns/divisions to have content that can be customized by users. There may be a more WP specific way to do this, but a simple way would be to have a db table with these elements associated with the post id, for example post_id, town_desc, town_mascot, etc. Then, in the WP template, run a query to see if custom elements exist. If not, echo some default text, otherwise echo the custom element text from the db. I think I'd also have the default text be different based upon the level, i.e. with states, divisions, and towns all different based on their level.

Your answer might lie in simply working with custom fields, perhaps with

https://wordpress.org/support/article/custom-fields/